# Add images from ImagePicker to CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to add images from my image picker to the collection view and then have the ability to add and remove images as i wish.

I have added the functionality to add images, but unsure how to remove the option to add images when the limit is reached.

Also removing the images from the array/collection view.

[image]

```
var arrayOfImages = [UIImage]()

let uploadImagesCell = UITableViewCell()

var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var cellImage = UIImageView()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var imagePicker = ImagePickerController()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width / 3 - 20, height: 111)
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame:  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width - 10, height: 150), collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.delegate   = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


    self.uploadImagesCell.addSubview(collectionView)

    arrayOfImages.append(UIImage.init(named: "c")!)
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayOfImages.count
}
var path: Int!

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    self.cellImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: cell.frame.size.height))
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    cellImage.image = arrayOfImages[indexPath.row]

    cell.addSubview(cellImage)


    return cell
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print("test")


        var configuration = Configuration()
            configuration.doneButtonTitle = "Finish"
            configuration.noImagesTitle = "Sorry! There are no images here!"
            configuration.recordLocation = false

            imagePicker = ImagePickerController(configuration: configuration)
            imagePicker.imageLimit = 1
            imagePicker.delegate = self

            present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func wrapperDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
public var imageAssets: [UIImage] {
    return AssetManager.resolveAssets(imagePicker.stack.assets)
}
func cancelButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController) {
    print("cancel")
}

func doneButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {


    let images = imageAssets[0]


    self.arrayOfImages.insert(images, at: 0)


    self.collectionView.reloadData()

    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Can you please crop your screenshot and re-upload it? Also, please remove all irrelevant code from your post (such as `didReceiveMemoryWarning`...)

Comment: you are in need of adding a cross button at  top right corner of collectionCell Tapping at the cross you  have to remove cell and array at the tapped index.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I have

Comment: @AbuUlHassan huh? I want the images from the picker to show in the collection view and the ability to add more images in with a limit of 4

Comment: check if imageAssets.count==photoLimit { //hide your add button}

Comment: @AbuUlHassan the photo limit is 1 for each image i want to upload, they get added into the array of images array which is linked with the collection view

Comment: its confusing :( if you want that in imagepickerController then you have to use a custom library for imagePicker :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a button inside the cell and use delegate or callback for the button .

```
import UIKit

class AttachCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var attachImageView: UIImageView!

    var delete_callback : ((_ identi : Int) -> ())?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    @IBAction func deleteBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        delete_callback?(self.tag)
    }
}
```

Add a call back inside collectionview delegate like below.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let identifier = "AttachCollectionViewCell"
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
        if let attachCell = cell as? AttachCollectionViewCell {
            attachCell.delete_callback = { (ident) -> Void in
                self.pickedImages.remove(at: ident)
                self.attachCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if imageAssets.count==photoLimit 
    { //display alert  you have reached the limit}
    else{print("test")
        var configuration = Configuration()
            configuration.doneButtonTitle = "Finish"
            configuration.noImagesTitle = "Sorry! There are no images here!"
            configuration.recordLocation = false

            imagePicker = ImagePickerController(configuration: configuration)
            imagePicker.imageLimit = 1
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: this is not what i need

Answer (score 0):

set the minus button on top right corner in your cell.

and this in your code

```
    cell.cancelBtn = {
            self. arrayOfImages.remove(at: indexPath.item - 1)
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
```

this will remove image from collection view and also from the array.